# Can I use something similar to Rails' 'has_many :through'?

Tags: typo3, datamapper, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

I'm trying to recreate a `has_many :through` relationship inside my extension. Is there something similar that I can use in TCA?

[Here is a link to the Rails docs for clarification](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TYPO3 has MM-relations with full handling, but what you want looks like qualified MM-relations.
This has not been implemented yet in TYPO3.

So you need to realize it by your own: have three models where one model has n:1 relations to the other two. All handling, like selections, needs to be done in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is that possible while still going through the database abstraction layer or would I need to drop down to raw SQL?

Comment: depending on your usage. be aware that the DBAL will be a lot of overhead as relations betweeen models will be realized with additional mm-records. I don't know whether you can simple enhance the default mm-record between two models to add your specific fields and build your own queries. This should be possible, but will it be supported with all BE-functions? at least you need your own routines (a wizard?) to edit this fields in the BE.